# how to implement Design on a T-Shirt functionality?

Tags: node.js, angular

- I have no idea  `https://www.customink.com/ndx/#/` about this kind of feature and i don't know where to
  start I tried google but i got lost so, i just wanna know how to achieve this kind of feature any help from anyone that
  would be awesome

Comment: It is a static image of a shirt where you drag and drop some images/texts.
So you should study the browser drag and drop feature.
It seems all images are created /rendered on the server-side so it would be nice to know about serverside image manipulation.

Comment: thanks Rene Gonzalez Venegas for your comment